# c# Writing a code that will manage hotel rooms/Calculations

Tags: c#

So I am trying to make a hotel manager using it's own class that can calculate the cost depending on how high up your room is, Ocean view, How many bedrooms, and it to spit out the cost depending on those 3 variables.

I am stuck because when I try running this without any calculations, just to see if it works so far it will not return/restate what I have inputted. There's an error Saying "FormatException occured"

I'm quite new to c#, so I appreciate any help that can be given.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myHotel
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Apartment myApartment = new Apartment();
        Console.WriteLine("Hotel Building Number:");
        myApartment.BuildingNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Hotel room number:");
        myApartment.ApartmentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of Bedrooms you have:");
        myApartment.Type = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 1 for Ocean View and 2 for no Ocean view:");
        myApartment.View = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
        myApartment.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", 
            myApartment.BuildingNumber, 
            myApartment.ApartmentNumber, 
            myApartment.Type, 
            myApartment.View, 
            myApartment.View);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
class Apartment
{
    public int BuildingNumber { get; set; }
    public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int View { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Format string for `Console.WriteLine` has 6 placeholders:

```
"{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}"
```

but you are passing only 5 arguments. Either add one more argument, or remove last placeholder.

---

Also if you want to display values from Apartment class instance, it might make sense to override it's `ToString()` method. E.g.:

```
class Apartment
{
    public int BuildingNumber { get; set; }
    public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int View { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"{BuildingNumber} {ApartmentNumber} {Type} {View} {Name}";
    }
}
```

Now displaying it will be simple as:

```
Console.WriteLine(myApartment);
```

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and it works great. 

Now If I wanted to add in variables depending on if there room has 1 bedroom 800$, 2bedrooms 850, 3bedrooms 900$. Using those number as the base prices then adding 50$ for ocean view, then 25$ if your apartment number is higher then 300. 

Would I make another string that is devoted to currency starting at 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Your format string has more spots for interpolation than you have parameters.  Try:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", 
        myApartment.BuildingNumber, 
        myApartment.ApartmentNumber, 
        myApartment.Type, 
        myApartment.View, 
        myApartment.View);
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it and it works! Now If I wanted to add in variables depending on if there room has 1 bedroom 800$, 2bedrooms 850, 3bedrooms 900$. Using those number as the base prices then adding 50$ for ocean view, then 25$ if your apartment number is higher then 300. Would I make another string that is devoted to currency starting at 0$? Then comparing to the number they input, like if they put in 1 for 1 bedroom, add 800$?